# Freestyle line doesn't show anymore

Tags: freestyle

The freestyle line used to show but it doesn't anymore and I can't figure out why.

I will link the file here:
[image]

Comment: In 2.8, Freestyle isn't previewing yet, in the way it did with Blender Internal, if that's what you mean?

Comment: No it just doens't show up when I do a full render..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After blood, sweat and tears I've decide to just copy my mesh and armature by selecting it and pressing ctrl + c and then in another file pressing ctrl + v and the line shows up in the new file just fine.

I don't know what the problem is in the previous file (I did transfer it via google drive maybe that messed something up?)

**Conclusion**: If something doesnt render properly try copying your mesh (and armature) to another file